# how to get from mysql using in same sequence using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this record in my database

```
| 29 | Mac  190:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200 |
```

the last column name is

> path_address

if I have a string like this

```
190:193:194:195
```

I want  MySQL to select the path_address that has same sequence
so I used this command

```
 $query_data = $module_model::where('path_address','LIKE',"$structure%")->limit(7)->get();
```

where structure is :190:193:194:195 and it is working fine, but what is happening is that if I have string like this

> 190:193:194:195:197

it is also return mac as a result of this query ,
how can I set my query to bring the string that have same sequence only and stop if it has broken sequence , so the accepted sequence will be  like this

190

190:193

190:193:194

190:193:194:195

190:193:194:195:196 and so on

but theses sequence must be rejected
190:194

190:193:194:196

190:193:196

190:193:194:195:196:198 etc .

Answer (score 0):

For example, you may use

```sql
WHERE path_address LIKE '$structure%'
   OR '$structure' LIKE CONCAT(path_address, '%')
```

First condition will return rows where `path_address` is not shorter than `$structure`, second - where it is not longer respectively.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37e2151914a420eda9dfc5532c98cbc7)

Comment: thank you  for your reply actually I used   LIKE '$structure%' but it return true for the broken sequence like this  190:193:194:195:197  where it must return false

Comment: @NetcomAsk *it return true for the broken sequence like this **190:193:194:195**:197 where it must return false* Really? I mark the pattern in your textlly. PS. Fiddle added. PPS. Or you mean something absolutely different... PPPS. Maybe "this record in my database" contains the pattern (`190:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200`) which must be used?